# Problema de validação em formulário com Opencart

Tags: php, formulário, opencart

Possuo um [site](http://oticasreiban.com.br/index.php?route=account/register) e-commerce no `opencart` e estou com um probleminha no campo RG que é o seguinte, quando o usuário se cadastra ele preenche todos os campos normalmente porem no campo RG existe aqueles usuários que tem um digito a menos no RG eles se cadastram normalmente no site mais quando vão efetuar uma compra não conseguem conclui-la pelo fato do RG estar com um número a menos gostaria de saber se é possível colocar um código que faça o seguinte quando o usuário cadastrar um RG com um digito a menos adicionar um 0 no campo para que ele fique completo. acredito que esse código vá dentro do `controller` do formulário não fui eu quem desenvolvi o site mais tenho que fazer essa alteração.

Answer (score 1):

O RG não tem numeração unificada. Um mesmo indivíduo pode ter RGs emitidos pelo governo local, pode também se utilizar de carteiras funcionais como o CREA ou o CRM ou identidades militares emitidas pelo Exército, por exemplo. Por isso acredito não ser recomendado você adotar qualquer tipo de validação do RG.